# Android: get id when Button is clicked

Tags: android, listview, button, sqlite

I'm creating a Dictionary that has a bookmark and i want to have an activity where i can delete individual data in a bookmark.. this is the sample layout that i want to do

[image]

at the left corner of each data there is a button that can delete the item is there a method of button that can get the _id of the item this is how i output my data in list view

`ourCursor = dbDictionaryHelper.getBookmarked();
startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
adapter = new DeleteBookmarkAdapter(ourCursor);
lvDeleteBookmark.setAdapter(adapter);`

```
    class DeleteBookmarkAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    DeleteBookmarkAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super(DeleteBookmarkActivity.this, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
        DictionaryHolder holder = (DictionaryHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, dbDictionaryHelper);
    }

    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deletebookmarkdata, parent,
                false);
        DictionaryHolder holder = new DictionaryHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return (row);
    }
}

static class DictionaryHolder implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView word = null;
    private Button btnRemove = null;

    DictionaryHolder(View row) {
        word = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvDeleteBookmark);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DictionaryHelper r) {
        word.setText(r.getName(c));
    }
```

hope you can help me... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView. The activity show a listview of all data you want. In this listview the touch action on an item delete it.
You will have a better design. User can click not only on a little button but on all row of the element to delete it.
In the list view use this method to implement delete action:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something when a list item is clicked
}
```

[Here the reference of ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: are there any other options for deleting an item? i need only to click to button to delete... btw thanks for sharing your idea

Answer (score 0):

You can just find button and set your custom listener:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String name = cursor.getString(itemNameIndex);
        boolean checked = cursor.getInt(itemCheckIndex) > 0;
        TextView nameTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        Button removeBtn= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.item_remove);
        checkChk.setOnClickListener(new OnRemoveItemClickListener(name));
        nameTxt.setText(name);
    }
@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        return view;
    }
```